# Who handles the IRP's and decides which IRP is to be sent and in which order?

Tags: windows, device-driver, wdk, wdm

While debugging the toaster driver in WDM my Bus_PnP has the IRP stack in which its assigned that which MINOR function is to be handled but who assignes it to IRP stack that which minor is to handled.

Answer (score 1):

The MAJOR function and MINOR function codes are assigned be the calling API, or the underlying OS. In this case, PnP, they will be assigned by the part of I/O subsystem that manages plug and play.

You probably want to read up on "[Implementing Plug and Play](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" on MSDN

It might be useful to also understand [IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation routine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

and [IO_STACK_LOCATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550659%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

In general if you are interested in WDM Windows drivers and internals a good read would be "Windows NT Device Driver Development" by Tony Mason and Peter Viscarola.